# Is it required to collapse a vector of strings into a standard expression for str_subset?

Tags: r, string

```
colours <- c("^red$", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple")
colour_match <- str_c(colours, collapse = "|")

has_colour <- str_subset(sentences, colour_match) # 1
has_colour_test <- str_subset(sentences, colours) # 2
```

Why do #1 & #2 return different results (why doesnt #2 work ) ?

Answer (score 1):

`str_subset` is vectorized over `string` and `pattern`. So when you pass `pattern` which has length more than 1, they are compared element-wise and shorter vector is recycled if needed.

Consider this smaller and simple example,

```
library(stringr)

fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pineapple")
str_subset(fruit, c("app","pe", "bana", "pin"))
#[1] "apple"    "pinapple"
```

The first pattern `"app"` is compared with `"apple"`, `"pe"` with `"banana"` and so on. Since only 1st and 4th value match, hence those are subsetted.

Whereas in another case, we collapse the regex argument and pass it as single value

```
str_subset(fruit, "app|pe|bana|pin")
#[1] "apple"    "banana"   "pear"     "pinapple"
```

So here `"app|pe|bana|pin"` is matched with every element of `fruit`.